# join in table for multiple column

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables [ table1, table2 ]

```
Table 1
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+--+--------------+
|  2 | Film       |
|  1 | Music      |
|  3 | OTHER      |
|  5 | Sports     |
|  4 | TV Content |
+----+------------+

Table 2
+----+-----+-----+
| id | id1 | id2 |
+----+-----+-----+
|  2 |   1 |   1 |
|  1 |   1 |   1 | 
|  3 |   2 |   1 |
|  5 |   3 |   1 |
|  4 |   4 |   1 |
+----+-----+-----+
```

and my desired output is

```
+------------+------------+----------+
| id_name    | id1_name   | id2_name |
+------------+------------+----------+
| film       | Music      | Music    |
| music      | Music      | Music    | Required Output
| other      | Film       | Music    |
| sports     | OTHER      | Music    |
| TV Content | TV Content | Music    |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

How can I do  this?

Comment: Prade, what have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? It's much easier for people to help you if you provide more information. Please have a look at the [ask] article in the help centre.

Comment: Which dbms are you using. (Remove two of the tagged ones.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have three different foreign keys, you need to do 3 different joins with the same table:

```
SELECT table1.name AS 'id_name',
       first.name AS 'id1_name',
       second.name AS 'id2_name'
FROM table2
    JOIN table1 ON
        table1.id = table2.id
    JOIN table1 first ON
        first.id = table2.id1
    JOIN table1 second ON
        second.id = table2.id2
```

Comment: If you want to get the name of the three columns, than yes :)

Comment: thanks its work for me ,